# Divide string only at line breaks

Tags: string-manipulation

I have a very simple problem but don'tk now how to solve it.

I have a string that looks like this:

string="a b c

d e f"

I want to break it ONLY at the line breaks, i.e. I want to get a list of the following two strings in return:

"a b c" and "d e f".

I.e. the answer should be {"a b c", "d e f"}.

However, if I use StringSplit[string], I instead get {"a","b","c","d","e","f"}.

How can I fix this? Why does Mathematica treat line breaks and whitespaces the same way?

Comment: Please have a look at [the documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringSplit.html). `StringSplit` can split at any pattern you like.

Answer (score 1):

You define "string" with 2 consecutive Newlines. With only one, you can write:

```
 StringSplit[s, "\n"]
```

However with several consecutive Newlines you must write:

```
StringSplit[s, "\n"] /. "" -> Sequence[]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string = "a b c

d e f";
StringSplit[string, {"\n\n"}] // InputForm
```

Answer (score 1):

This pattern will work for any kind of line ending and will automatically delete empty lines:

```
StringSplit[string, ("\r" | "\n")..]
```

> {"a b c", "d e f"}